# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

**The goal is to implement 3D modeling on the server side using node.js**.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var OBJselector = document.querySelector("nav select[name='obj']");
        var infos = document.querySelector("div#infos");
        var generatedImage = infos.querySelector("img#generated");
```

**I will skip the unnecessary parts.**

```
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: canvas,
            precision: "highp",
            premultipliedAlpha: true,
            alpha: true,
            antialias: true
        });

        renderer.setSize(width, height);

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 0.1, 10000);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);

        var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.rotateSpeed = 2.0;
        controls.zoomSpeed = 0.2;
        controls.minDistance = 0;

        window.addEventListener("resize", function( event ){

            width = window.innerWidth;
            height = window.innerHeight;

            renderer.setSize(width, height);

            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        }, false);

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000);
        scene.add(ambient);

        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
        light.position.set(15, 5, 5);
        scene.add(light);

        var hemisphereLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xFFFFFF, 0x001133, 1);
        scene.add(hemisphereLight);

        var object3d;
```

**This is the second part of the code.**

```
function doMagicThings( fileName ){

            generatedImage.src = "models/" + fileName + "/" + fileName + ".obj.png";
            infos.style.opacity = 1;

            // Generate the THREE-JS Object3D from the image.
            var obj = new OBJImg({
                image: "models/" + fileName + "/" + fileName + ".obj.png",
                receiveShadow: false,
                castShadow: false,
                useWorker: false,
                renderer: renderer,
                onComplete: function( event ){

                    console.log("RAW datas:", event.detail, " (usefull for vanilla WebGL)");
```

**Raw data is entered by objimg.js**

```
},
                    onError: function( event ){

                    console.error(event);

                }
            });

            scene.remove(object3d);
            controls.reset();

            object3d = obj.getObject3D();
            object3d.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add(object3d);

        };

        OBJselector.addEventListener("change", function(){

            doMagicThings(this.value);

        }, false);

        doMagicThings(OBJselector.value);

        function render( now ){

            window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

            controls.update();

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        };

        window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

    }, false);
```

However, the following **error** occurs

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined`

**Each raw data of the 3D model is calculated. However, it is not created as a 3D model.**
**How should I change this code?**

Comment: Your `object3d` is `undefined`, make sure that `obj.getObject3D()` is returning something.

Comment: what is returned in object3d?

Comment: My guess: that `.getObject3D()` function is *attempting* to return a value from an asynchronous callback. Because that cannot be done, the variable `object3d` ends up `undefined`.

Comment: Each raw data of the 3D model is calculated. However, it is not created as a 3D model.

Comment: @Geonhee, could you please update the code with your `getObject3D()` method? this error occurs because of `obj.getObject3D()`  returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll put in additional source code.